# Ubuntu куча процессов mysqld --daemonize

Tags: php, mysql, linux, процесс, daemon

Висит целая куча процессов

`/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid`

Из-за чего такое может быть? Может ли из-за того, что какой-то mysqli не закрыл соединение в php-скрипте? Возможно ли как-то быстро найти из какого скрипта растут ноги?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1. Это не куча процессов, это потоки. 2. Это нормальное состояние даже для "не используемого" сервера. MySQL всегда держит под рукой пул потоков для быстрого обслуживания соединений 3. По этому скриншоту можно "нагадать" все что угодно, поэтому предварительный диагноз - у вас все хорошо.

Comment: А что по логам?
Если эти процессы не грузят ЦП, то коллега выше прав.

Comment: @НиколайГабараев а какие логи посмотреть, чтобы быть уверенным?) В error.log всё норм. Одни Note:
2019-10-07T11:15:46.356419Z 0 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
2019-10-07T11:15:46.356498Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
2019-10-07T11:15:46.448939Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2019-10-07T11:15:46.449173Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.27-0ubuntu0.18.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
2019-10-07T11:15:46.487417Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 191007 14:15:46

Comment: @НиколайГабараев ЦПУ они не грузят, что собственно и отражено на скриншоте - 9-я колонка со значениями "0.0".

Comment: @theblackpost сопсно этот лог и показывает, что БД у вас бездельничает. Так  что норм)

Comment: Ясно. Ну, можете добавить как решение)